# R - `try` in conjunction with capturing ALL console output?

Tags: r, error-handling

Here's a piece of code I'm working with:

```
install.package('BiocManager');BiocManager::install('UniProt.ws')
requireNamespace('UniProt.ws')
uniprot_object <- UniProt.ws::UniProt.ws(
  UniProt.ws::availableUniprotSpecies(
    pattern = '^Homo sapiens$')$`taxon ID`)
query_results <- try(
    UniProt.ws::select(
      x = uniprot_object,
      keys = 'BAA08084.1',
      keytype = 'EMBL/GENBANK/DDBJ',
      columns = c('ENSEMBL','UNIPROTKB')))
```

This particular key/keytype combination is non-productive and produces the following output:

```
Getting mapping data for BAA08084.1 ... and ACC
error while trying to retrieve data in chunk 1:
  no lines available in input
continuing to try
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = `*vtmp*`) : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

Of the two `[eE]rror`s reported only the second is a 'proper' `R` error object and given the use of `try` accordingly captured in the variable `query_result`.

I am, however, desperate to capture the other `error` bit (`no lines available in input`) to inform downstream programmatic processes.

After playing with a plethora of `capture.output`, `sink`, `purrr::quietly`, etc. options found by startpaging (googling), I continue to fail capturing that bit. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try the "tryCatch" function? Usually works better than "try".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @user2554330 s most excellent answer, I constructed an ugly thing that does exactly what I want:

1. try to execute the statement
2. don't fail fatally
3. leave no ugly messages
4. allow me access to `error`s and `message`s

So here it is in all it's despicable glory:

```
  saveMessages <- c()
  query_results <- suppressMessages(
    withCallingHandlers(
      try(
        UniProt.ws::select(
          x = uniprot_object,
          keys = 'BAA08084.1',
          keytype = 'EMBL/GENBANK/DDBJ',
          columns = c('ENSEMBL','UNIPROTKB')),
        silent = TRUE),
      message = function(e)
        saveMessages <<- c(saveMessages, conditionMessage(e))))
```

Comment: I wouldn't call this "ugly".  You want to do two different things for messages and errors:  save the former but continue calculations, stop calculations but save the message for the latter.  So you really need two functions:  either `try()` or `tryCatch()` for the errors, and `withCallingHandlers` for the messages.

Answer (score 3):

As @Csd suggested, you could use `tryCatch`.  The message that you are after is printed by the `message()` function in R, not `stop()`, so `try()` will ignore it.  To capture output from `message()`, use code like this:

```
query_results <- tryCatch(
   UniProt.ws::select(
     x = uniprot_object,
     keys = 'BAA08084.1',
     keytype = 'EMBL/GENBANK/DDBJ',
     columns = c('ENSEMBL','UNIPROTKB')), 
   message = function(e) conditionMessage(e))
```

This will abort evaluation when it gets any message, and return the message in `query_results`.  If you are doing more than debugging, you probably want the message saved, but evaluation to continue.  In that case, use `withCallingHandlers` instead.  For example,

```
saveMessages <- c()
query_results <- withCallingHandlers(
   UniProt.ws::select(
     x = uniprot_object,
     keys = 'BAA08084.1',
     keytype = 'EMBL/GENBANK/DDBJ',
     columns = c('ENSEMBL','UNIPROTKB')), 
   message = function(e) 
               saveMessages <<- c(saveMessages, conditionMessage(e)))
```

When I run this version, `query_results` is unchanged (because the later error aborted execution), but the messages are saved:

```
saveMessages
[1] "Getting mapping data for BAA08084.1 ... and ACC\n"                                                    
[2] "error while trying to retrieve data in chunk 1:\n    no lines available in input\ncontinuing to try\n"
```

Comment: Really cool - the right track. Now how to proceed even if there's an error (like try)?

Comment: See answer below for an UGLY construct based on your excellent observations.